# Background div not showing

Tags: html, background

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<style type="text/css">
body {
background-color: #444669;
}
#1 {
background-color: #DD2124;
height: 337px;
width: 388px;
}
</style>

<body>
<div id="1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to make a section of div with a different background color but it doesn't even show at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id's in CSS cannot start with a number. Simply changing the `#1` to, for example, `#first`, should work.

**Preview:**

https://jsfiddle.net/uLwn05q2/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #444669;
}

#first {
    background-color: #DD2124;
    height: 337px;
    width: 388px;
}
</style>

<body>
<div id="first"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update:**

There is a trick you can use to actually keep the id as a number:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #444669;
}

[id='1']  {
    background-color: #DD2124;
    height: 337px;
    width: 388px;
}
</style>
```